# Concat and order variables with mulitple values?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I expose my problem, I have actualy 2 variables `s1` and `s2` with multiple values inside

ex :

```
s1 = [4906,145,62,56];
s2 = ["text1","text2","text3","text4"];
```

I'm searching the best way for concatenate `s1` and `s2` as:

```
data = [["text1",4906],["text2",145],["text3",62],["text4",56]];
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: any attempt from your side ?

Comment: `var result = s1.map((x,i)=>[s2[i], x]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you make sure that both the arrays are in the same size, you can do something like:

```
 data = [];
 for(i=0; i<s1.length; i++){
    var temp = [];
    temp.push(s1[i]);
    temp.push(s2[i]); 
    data.push(temp);
  }
```

Why not hold array of objects instead of more arrays?

```
data = [ { title: "text", value: 4353 } , { ... } ]
```

Comment: thanks @Shaniqwa this is the best code for me. FYI i need this for pie chart that want this concat in enter...

Answer (score 0):

just loop through using the index as an index for both arrays (as long as you want to concat the vars in the same spot of each array)